# Axis2 Web Service : The method getConstructor(Class[]) in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments (Class<T>)

Tags: java, web-services

I used axis2 1.6.2, Eclipse Luna, Mac 10.9.4, JDK 1.8, tomcat 8.0 to implement a web service demo program. As I think the code snippet for web service is not necessary for this error. The Error is in this snippet only in Client STUB  :

```
  java.lang.reflect.Constructor constructor = exceptionClass.getConstructor(String.class);
  java.lang.Exception ex = (java.lang.Exception) constructor.newInstance(f.getMessage());
```

and the suggestions are 
1) The method getConstructor(Class[]) in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Class)

2) The method newInstance(Object[]) in the type Constructor is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String)

what this error suggest and how to resolve it. Thank You

Comment: This looks like legal Java to me, so you must be using a broken tool somewhere.  If you change it to `exception.Class.getConstructor(new Class<?>[] {String.class})`, does that make it work?  Similarly `constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {f.getMessage()})`.  I'm just guessing, though--I don't know anything about some of these tools.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but I came across the same issue:
Right click on your project: "properties" > "Project Facets" 
and make sure "Java" is marked 1.5 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Basically your java compiler compliance level might be set to 1.4 or below. Just Right click on your project in eclipse >> Properties >> Java compiler >> Check Enable Project Specific settings >> change compiler compliance level to 1.5 or above >> click Apply and the project will be rebuild.

TAdAAN !! your issue is resolved.